# All details for each reference appear in separate lines

Tags: bibtex, formatting

I have used different bibliography styles (bibtex) but I keep on getting the output (attached) where each detail of a reference begins on a new line. Is there a way to have the references in running text?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like the baselineskip is higher the problem.

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example, which shows the problem. It makes it easier to fix if people know what you are doing. And welcome!

Comment: Many thanks! I hope that the updated information suffices.

Answer (score 1):

The effect is the expected effected for the `openbib` option of the `report` document class.

If one open the generated `.bbl` files, one can notice that it contains `\newblock`s commands. The `openbib` option instructs to treat `\newblock` as new line command.